# iOS-Swift Dynamic UIViewController use with multiple custom defined attribute type

Tags: ios, swift, generics, dynamic, swift-protocols

So I have a ViewController that has an attribute of type "Something", this same view controller I want to use it with a different attribute of type "something1", I was thinking of making a protocol for each custom type "something" and "something1" and they would deliver what I need inside the ViewController, but both are structs, and it will not work as both are value types.

my example code is the following:

```
final class DynamicViewController: UIViewController {

private let attribute: CustomType // something or Somthing1
private let stackView: UIStackView

init(attribute: CustomType) {
    self.attribute = attribute
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupViews()
}

private func setupViews() {
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(scrollView)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate ([
        ...
    ])

    scrollView.addSubview(stackView)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    ...
    ])

    getInfoLabels()
}

private func getInfoLabels() {
    if let attribute = attribute {
        numerateInObjectAndGetLabel(obj: attribute)
    }
}

private func numerateInObjectAndGetLabel(obj: Any) {
    let mirroredAttr = Mirror(reflecting: obj)
    for (_, attr) in mirroredAttr.children.enumerated() {
        if let txts = attr.value as? [String] {
            for txt in txts {
                stackView.addArrangedSubview(getLabel(for: txt))
            }
        }
    }
}

private func getLabel(for text: String) -> UILabel {
    let label = UILabel()
    ....
    return label
}}
```

I do have solution of making multiple optional attributes with multiple custom types, but in my case I have more than 10 custom types so it will get ugly..

Is there a way in solving this with neat and clean approach? I really do not like redundant code.

Answer (score 1):

So as a solution I made a Protocol and defined it inside the struct, but I had to make the struct not codable as in my case not a problem, if it is a problem then you can use init(from:) and with coding keys.

then I made my DynamicViewController extend that protocol, of course I needed to set the structs delegate (protocol) to the view controller.

answer:

```
let dynamicViewController = DynamicViewController()
    something.delegate = dynamicViewController
    navigationController?.pushViewController(abuseOverdosageViewController, animated: true)

------------------------------------------------------------

final class DynamicViewController: UIViewController, CustomProtocol {

private let stackView: UIStackView

init(attribute: CustomType) {
    self.attribute = attribute
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupViews()
}

private func setupViews() {
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(scrollView)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate ([
        ...
        ])

    scrollView.addSubview(stackView)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        ...
        ])
}

/// PROTOCOL
func getView(view: UIView) {
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(view)
   }
}
-------------------------------------------


protocol CustomProtocol {
   func getView(view: UIView)
}


-------------------------------------------
struct Something {

public var delegate: CustomProtocol? {
    didSet {
        numerateInObjectAndGetLabel(obj: self)
    }
}

/// attributes
public var ......
public var .....
public var ....
public var ...
public var ..


private func numerateInObjectAndGetLabel(obj: Any) {
    let mirroredAttr = Mirror(reflecting: obj)
    for (_, attr) in mirroredAttr.children.enumerated() {
        if let txts = attr.value as? [String] {
            for txt in txts {
                delegate?.getView(view: getLabel(for: txt))
            }
        }
    }
}

private func getLabel(for text: String) -> UILabel {
    let label = UILabel()
    ...
    return label
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best idea is change your variable "attribute" to be a protocol and then use classes implements this protocol.

By the way:

```
final class DynamicView: UIViewController
```

You should rename it to:

```
DynamicViewController
```

because it's of type UIViewController, not UIView.

Comment: Thanks for the hint but that's not the real code ;), but will edit the question.

Comment: Okay, but still. I think you should just hold protocol as variable and then your "SomethingTypes" should implement this protocol.

Comment: so to be more clear both attributes as structs that represent a JSON `struct Something: Codable {...}`, a protocol will not work. as I already said in the question. but please do correct me maybe I did not understand you.

Comment: Structs can implement many protocols. Just use:
`struct Something: Codable, Somethingable {...}`
why do you think protocols won't work here?

Comment: ah ok I was thinking the other way around; to define the protocol inside the struct and the view controller will extend the protocol. I do the magic in the struct and the delegate method will be triggered in the view controller.

Comment: also check your profile you have a typo in it, I guess you meant **iOS Developer** and not **iOS Deveoper** ;).